# How to change specific element in MYSQL datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the datetime format in my Mysql table such as this, on **my_date** column.

```
 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

which will be populated with year, month, day, and time, from [SELECT]'s,
with the onBlur Javascript function.

I need to **update**, at any time, only **one value** of the datetime above.

So when I will trigger the year SELECT, it will change the year in the database. When I trigger the month, it will modify the month.

I've searched around and could not find any relevant answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to only update one? If you have all the values, why not update the full date, even if only one component has changed? I doubt it will be more efficient to to update specific parts of it.

Comment: If this is actually necessary, you can probably use `DATE_ADD`. Something like `UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn=DATE_ADD(mycolumn, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` (change `MONTH` to `DAY` etc as needed, and change `1` to `-1` or other numbers as needed.

Comment: Agreed, this seems pointless. The form you're using will surely give you the whole date, so just use that to overwrite the previous value

Answer (score 0):

I have used the first suggestion in the comments, which is to set the full date in my selects (year, month, day, and time), and then use a simple [BUTTON] with onClick -> call to an AJAX that would save the whole date once.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use trick with date_format function for change part of datetime filed like:

```
-- change year
update tbl set d = date_format(d, '2020-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');

-- change month
update tbl set d = date_format(d, '%Y-03-%d %H:%i:%S');
```

[Test MySQL date_time online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/57ef64004371a506b10c6a28380c05f5/)